# Editing a line tag inside svg tag using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, svg, line

I am trying to create a line to draw from one side of the window to the other. Using javascript I want it to be at a certain point. I want to detect window size and the nav bar height. The problem I had was that the line is not being displayed.

Here is my javascript and html code:

```
      <script>
        function createLineScreenWidth() {

          var elem = getElementsByTagName("svg")[0];
          var line = getElementsByTagName("line")[0];
          var y_pos = getElementByID("navbar").height;

          elem.style.height = "10";
          elem.style.width =  screen.width;

          line.style.stroke = rgb(188, 204, 229);
          line.x2 = screen.width;
          line.y1 = line.y2 = y_pos;
        }
      </script>
        <div class="navbar" id="navbar">
            <nav>
                <a href="/contact/"><div class="pageIcon">CONTACT</div></a>
                <a href="/products/"><div class="pageIcon">PRODUCTS</div></a>
                <a><div class="pageIcon onpageIconChange">ABOUT</div></a>
            </nav>
        </div>
        <svg onload="createLineScreenWidth()">
          <line x1="0" style="stroke-width: 2;" />
        </svg>
```

Comment: First you have to remove some errors there is document.getElementsById and some for TagName
2nd there is no rgb function instead wrap in double quotes "rgb(0,0,0)"

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>ds</title>
  <style>
    #navbar{
      position: relative;

    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <script>
    function createLineScreenWidth() {

      var elem = document.getElementsByTagName("svg")[0];
      var line = document.getElementsByTagName("line")[0];

      var y_pos = document.getElementById("navbar").clientHeight;


      elem.style.height = "100";
      elem.style.width =  screen.width;


      // line.style.stroke = "red";
      // line.x2 = screen.width;
      // line.y1 = line.y2 = y_pos;

      line.setAttribute('x1','0');
      line.setAttribute('y1',y_pos);
      line.setAttribute('x2',screen.width);
      line.setAttribute('y2',y_pos);
      line.setAttribute("stroke", "rgb(188, 204, 229)")
      elem.appendChild(line);
    }
  </script>
  <div class="navbar" id="navbar">
    <nav>
      <a href="/contact/"><div class="pageIcon">CONTACT</div></a>
      <a href="/products/"><div class="pageIcon">PRODUCTS</div></a>
      <a><div class="pageIcon onpageIconChange">ABOUT</div></a>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <svg onload="createLineScreenWidth()">
    <line x1="0" style="stroke-width: 2;" />
  </svg>
</body>
</html>
```

Actually there were lot of errors

1. missing document.get
2. it was clientHeight not height
3. there is no rgb function instead you have to wrap that value in double quotes
4. last but not least instead of line. I'm using .setAttribute which is more clear what we are doing IMO

Comment: I have made the changes you have mentioned but it still did not work. I'm not sure what to do.. By the way thank you

Comment: I mean in the IDE I use. I use atom as an IDE and then when I try it in a browser the problem does not change